# Inspect web application page memory consumption

Tags: asp.net, memory, web, stack

I have a web application made with asp.net 4.0 in visual studio 2010. The application runs on a windows server 2012 with 2gb of RAM installed, and the OS takes about 40-50% of the RAM.

All the pages are fine when it comes to memory consumption but there is one page that i know its the largest of them all that when i access it for the first time it takes like 10 seconds to load and the memory from the server (as seen in task manager) goes quickly from 50 to 80%. After that i receive an error (logged in a log file on the server) about the stack being full.

I think this is because the memory consumption is too high so before i buy more RAM i need to know how can i see and fix this in visual studio. The session state has only very few data in it so it's not the culprit. It might be caused by too many variables, DataTables and sql queries... I don't store alot of data in the datatables.

It would be wonderful if i could see all the collections and variables how much memory they use... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: The exact error is: **Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.**

Comment: Do you mean "Stack Overflow"?

Comment: no its not that, i updated my question with the exact error message. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bought more RAM and the problem went away. I don't think there is a specific problem with the page. It uses a little over 600 MB of RAM (when it's first rendered - big page) and that's why with only 2 GB of RAM on a server was not enough for my application.